# Activity loading time issue( performance issue while loading Activity)

Tags: java, android

Am moving from one Activity to another activity, in second activity am showing the listview. Am using  arraylist's data to fill the listview, so for that i have used "for" condition for looping. so for that looping its taking time to load that page. That page loading time is depending up on the data in the arraylist, if there is more data in the arraylist then looping taking time. 
Is there any way to reduce page loading time.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look into doing your long-running logic in an AsyncTask, and when it's completed, display your listview results.  You can find more info on this at:

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

i have done same thing but my problem is in first activity one search button is there if i click that button it will do some backgrond process for that i have used Async Task, at that time i have displayed progress dialog. in post execute i have dismissed that dialog box. after completing the background process here it is moving to next activity an it is displying listview in next activity, so i have already displayed progress dialog one time.